# cuPrintf cuda function

Tags: cuda, printf

I want to use the cuPrintf function, and I get it from SDK. In the readme file they write the following

> Use The cuPrintf package consists of two device functions (i.e. called
>   from within a CUDA kernel) and three host functions (i.e. called from
>   within the host application). These are packaged in a single
>   cuPrintf.cu file, along with declarations included in a separate
>   cuPrintf.cuh header file. To use cuPrintf in your application, you
>   must do one of the following:
>
> a)    Either: Include the header-file cuPrintf.cuh at the top of your
>   device code, and add cuPrintf.cu to your makefile or build
>   command-line so that the file is included in your program.
>
> b)    Or: Directly “#include cuPrintf.cu” at the top of your device
>   code. In this case you should not add this file to your
>   makefile/build-command, and you should take care to only include it
>   once in your entire project.

I tried some ways but all of them give me error, ( fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cuPrintf.cuh': No such file or directory )

- I put the 'cuPrintf.cu' in the header folder in the VB 2008, and
  include  but give me error, and change it to
  cuPrintf.cuh but also don't work.
- I put both files in the extension of the project , and include them
  in the code , and also give me error.

Any suggestions about how to fix it, I need this function for my code.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be be more specific about the error messages you get during compilation?

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the advice, I edited it and wrote the error.

Comment: So your question really has nothing to do with cuPrintf, it is basically how to configure a CUDA VS2008 project to import a header file from a non-standard path?

Comment: As an aside, if you can use SM 2.0 or above, you don't need the cuPrintf function: there is a built in printf

Comment: @talonmies I though it's regarding the setting or something like that,because I use printf without any problem..thanks for your replay

Comment: @flipchart I have to use cuPrintf , coz printf works only in the host..thanks for your replay

Comment: printf can be used in device code on SM 2.0 or above. NVIDIA built in a hardware version of it so that kernels can use it for debugging, etc. See section B.14 of the C programming guide guide http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I solved my error , by this way :

put both files ".cu & .cuh" in the same path of the project , and include "cuPrintf.cu" in the top of the code  and delete the .cu file from the header

Hope this will help who face the same error